# Append jquery file at first (change the order of js files)

Tags: jquery

I am newbie to jquery and want to ask a simple question. I have a jquery file say `asdfg.js`.

This file requires `jquery.js`.

In this file file I am checking if the jquery.js is already loaded or not. If the jquery is not loaded then include the js file.

I am using the following code :

```
if (window.jQuery) {
    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
} else {
    var elmScript = document.createElement('script');
    elmScript .src = 'http://localhost/new_customer/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'; // change file to your jQuery library
    elmScript .type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( elmScript );
}
```

But this file loads the `jquery.js` after `asdfg.js` file in which i am working. So what can I do if I want to load this `jquery.js` before `asdfg.js` ?

Comment: Why don't you just include jQuery in your HTML before you include `asdfg.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a function, call it directly if jQuery is loaded, otherwise put it into the `.onload` on the script element.

Something like:

```
if(window.jQuery) {
  myCode();
} else {
  var elmScript = document.createElement('script');
  elmScript.src = 'http://localhost/new_customer/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'; // change file to your jQuery library
  elmScript.type = 'text/javascript';        
  elmScript.onload = myCode;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( elmScript );
}

function myCode() {
  // use jQuery here...
}
```

Comment: @lord_linus, you need to put all the contents of your code that use jQuery inside that function, so it runs when it's supposed to.

Comment: Thanks Dogbert, This answer solved my problem, actually the problem was of case-sensitivity

Answer (score 1):

Instead of you can try something like this:

```
document.getElementById("myList").insertBefore(newItem,existingItem);
```

Comment: Thank u Zenith.. There is no prependchild

Comment: Hey meenakshi, what should I do if I dont know the Id of the div